# Can I encode a 64-bit negative immediate in x86?

Tags: assembly, x86, 32bit-64bit, twos-complement, integer-arithmetic

I'm trying to teach myself x86, and I've run across the need to return an immediate, negative number:

```
.text
.align 4,0x90
.globl _scheme_entry
_scheme_entry:
movl $-42, %eax
ret
```

When I print the return-value of this function (`printf("%" PRIdPTR "\n", scheme_entry())`, I get a nonsense number:

```
$ ./neg                                                 
4294967254
```

I'm guessing this is because it's a 32-bit negative, 00000000FFFFFFFF, instead of a 64-bit negative, FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF.

How can I store a constant 64-bit value directly in an assembler function? Do I have to encode it as two separate instructions?

Comment: Aren't you printing it wrong? `scheme_entry` seems to return a 32bit integer (if not, then why are you putting it in `eax`?)

Comment: gcc normally aligns function entry points to 16 bytes.  There's also no reason to force the padding to be single-byte NOP (because it will never run).  Use `.p2align 4` to align to `1<<4`.  (For such a tiny function, an 8-byte boundary would cover the whole function, so you might `.p2align 3`.)  Modern CPUs aren't as sensitive to code alignment as older CPUs, but it's generally still a good idea when the NOP padding won't execute.

Comment: @PeterCordes quite a bit of that is over my head — I'm following along [a compiler-writing tutorial](http://scheme2006.cs.uchicago.edu/11-ghuloum.pdf), which is intentionally having us use `gcc`'s output for tiny C inputs to decide what to emit from our compilers. The boilerplate above was copied basically verbatim, but I haven't yet learned what it does! :x

Comment: I don't know if you can access to 64 bits' registers, as the RAX's register, with your compiler/language (80686+); in case it is true, you could write MOV $-42,%RAX; the function result must be of 64 bits' type anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32-bit immediates for 32-bit instructions (like `movl`) are used as-is, and [writing EAX zeros the upper 32 bits of RAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177137/why-do-most-x64-instructions-zero-the-upper-part-of-a-32-bit-register).  You're not getting nonsense, you're getting `2^32 - 42`, which is exactly what you should expect, because x86 uses 2's complement signed integers.

32-bit immediates for instructions with 64-bit operand-size are sign-extended to 64 bits.

Use `mov $-42, %rax` to return a negative 64-bit value, instead of a positive 64-bit value just slightly below 2^32.  (Using `%rax` as the destination implies a 64-bit operand size, i.e. `movq`.)

Use a debugger to see values in registers.

Comment: This is excellent info! Yes, I was aware of two's-complement; but `%rax` (and `mov` vs `movl`, apparently?) were the pieces I was missing here. I'll run with this! Thank you!

Comment: @ELLIOTTCABLE Rather its movl vs movq. The suffix can be omitted if it is clear from the operands.